# counter graph for time series graphs

Tags: r, graph, ggplot2, time-series, counter

For the following data

```
time<- c(1:10)
age<- c(11:20)
dummy<-c(0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
d<- data.frame(time, age,dummy)
```

I would like to create a graph that consists of 10 rectangles stacked horizontally spanning the width of the graph, with the color of the rectangle corresponding to dummy=1 mapped on age, and the label of age printed. Looking something like
[image]

I"m creating a time series of cross-sectional graphs and want to create and automatic "counter" that would show me the location in time. This "counter" graph would be stacked on top of the other, more complex, graph, both connected to the counter variable.

## Question:

What's the best strategy in creating such graph with ggplot2?

Comment: Please share the plotting code you've tried so far and where you're running into issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a start at least. I'll use `geom_time` to draw squares

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(d, aes(x=factor(time), y=factor(1), fill=factor(dummy))) +
   geom_tile(color="black") + 
   geom_text(data=subset(d, dummy==1), aes(x=factor(time), y=factor(1), label=age)) + 
   scale_fill_manual(values=c("0"="white", "1"="green"), guide="none")  +
   scale_x_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +  scale_y_discrete(expand=c(0,0)) +
   theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I was looking for! I started thinking in terms of stacked bargraph  and couldn't get out of that mind frame. Thanks, @MrFlick!